# cannot create a SortedList having another SortedList

Tags: c#, collections

```
SortedList<int, string> months = new SortedList<int, string>();
SortedList<int, SortedList> all = new SortedList<int, SortedList>();
```

i want to create a SortedList which contains another sorted list of type of 'months' as in the above code snippet.

```
months.Add(1, "January");
all.Add(2012,months);
```

i get error

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedList' to 'System.Collections.SortedList'

m confused...

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to specify the type arguments for the inner `SortedList`, and it found a non-generic one, which is a different type. Do this:

```
var all = new SortedList<int, SortedList<int, string>>();
```

Comment: thanks Matti .. i need one more help..how to obtain reference of inner SortedList..i want to update it ...depending on the key supplied...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to name your parameters (otherwise it's a different type). Try this:

```
SortedList<int, SortedList<int, string> > all = new SortedList<int, SortedList<int, string> >();
```